# A new tag or a new StackExchange site? Advice requested

Tags: discussion, support, tags, outsourcing, tag-creation-process

I'm an active member of a script-programmer community based on an expert application software for (scientific) image analysis. The software is a wide spread industry standard, but the scripting language within is less well-known. So far, the user community has been self-organized mainly in closed mailing lists, missing out on the great opportunities community sites like StackOverflow are offering, in particular the open access & participation nature of it, which helps growth enormously.

I would like to change this, but I could need some help/advice.

My impression is, that the current community would be hard pressed to get over the hurdles of Area 51 as a stand-alone site. This, and the fact that many of the questions border to 'general coding' or algorithm questions would suggest to me, that the community would be better served by a special tag within the stackoverflow site. (Similar to some programming language tags.) I know there are several 'experts' out there (including me) who would be willing to answer questions, and there is for sure no lack of potential knowledge seekers.

I now wonder, if there is something similar to Area 51 just for tags, i.e. if it would be possible to introduce the tag and then see, if it is taken on by the community? My problem is, that while I've been using StackOverflow for 3 years now, I have not gathered enough reputation to create this tag (yet), and I also wanted to first discuss this here.

I deliberately did not name the software in this posting to not appear to be promoting or advertising. It is commercial software, but free basic versions giving full access to the main software plus its scripting language are available. The software is currently mainly used for (electron) microscopy images, but really is a general purpose image/data analysis program (Up to 5D data). The current 'closed' community I know about has about 200 active members, but the user base of the software is orders of magnitude higher, and interest in 'scripting' has recently increased a lot.

I would appreciate any help or advice from some of the stackOverflow veterans.
Thanks & regards.

Comment: The appropriate way to go is: Wait until a handful of good on-topic questions about your system are asked on SO, and then ask ask on Meta (if not in a comment on those questions) for someone to add the tag you want to those questions. Best have a tag-wiki prepared to add directly afterwards. Obvious seeding questions are not a good idea btw, they might lead to some backlash. Anyway, I'm sure there are duplicates of this question already on this meta or at least [meta.SE]

Comment: Read some of the questions with tag [meta-tag:outsourcing] and especially the linked [meta.SE]-posts addressing the issues, and containing a wealth of valuable advice and guidance.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I'll read some of the other posts (some I had already) and think about it. The problem I had with the "wait until a handful of ..." option was, that I didn't want to redirect community members to SO if their questions don't seem appropriate (and/or can not be picked out by experts in the scripting language).  Hence I wondered about the chicken & egg problem: First the tag, or first the questions ?  I think the tenor is: First the questions...

Comment: Well, there cannot be first the tag, as tags are created by users having at least 1500 reputation attaching it to a question, regardless if those are new or old. As bad questions are removed, tags without questions are automatically pruned.

Comment: Understood. I've started pointing people of the community towards SO and asking them to put their questions (and some reference to the according software) here. I just hope I (and others) will be able to pick them up! (I'll just have to keep a closer eye on SO for a while, I guess...)

Comment: You an set up a google alert to email you all new matches to a search.