# Should the [dm-script] tag be created?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

This is a follow up to the this [initial question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268384/a-new-tag-or-a-new-stackexchange-site-advice-requested) on introducing a new tag. I have been following the advise/suggestions given in the according answers.

Within the last 2 months, the 'sub-group' I'm trying to establish at SO has received 12 questions of 7 different users, which is surprisingly successful considering the limited user-base of the programming language. I've done my best to 'manage' and nourish this subgroup and will continue to do so, with the aim of helping it reaching 'critical mass'.

So far, SO has been a very nice place to do this, as it not only provides a nice public place to search/receive specific answers to the scripting language in question, but at the same time opens up the perspective to different languages (and hence approaches).

---

*My question is: Is this current level of participation already sufficient to warrant introduction of a new tag or should I keep on doing it in this manner for longer?*

---

Currently, users are asked to utilize the name of the programming language in the actual question such that it can be picked-up by text-search. This works, but it is a bit confusing for one-time askers or beginners. I've also recently seen (and edited out) the misappropriate use of another tag ( *DM* ) which would fit the community as it is a regularly used acronym for the software (DigitalMicrograph).

Although I'm building up, I still lack the required reputation to create the tag myself, so I'm asking the opinion of the more experienced users here.

A suggested tag-name would be "DM-script" or "DM-scripting". "DigitalMicrograph" would also work, but it is the brand-name of the software and it is not the aim to do advertising here.

Comment: How many questions (especially well-received ones) are there by now? If there are a handful or more, someone will gladly add your tag of choice, but decide now. Also, think about the tag-wiki and excerpt.

Comment: 12 questions which were all suitable and valid. So far, I have answered them all and most have been accepted. I'll bee taking care of the tag-wiki. Not sure what you mean by excerpt at the moment though.

Comment: Well, adding [tag:dm-script] for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the 12 questions to use the tag. Can I write the wiki-text with my current rep, or should I prepare and send/post it somewhere?

Comment: Suggest it directly on the tag-wiki page. But read the tag-guidelines before.

Comment: BTW: You might want to remove fluff and generally improve the presentation of questions a bit more aggressively.

Comment: Thanks, I've suggested a wiki now. It's my first, so I hope it fits the scheme. Edits welcomed. (Right now, I do not want to over-do editing of questions as of not to frighten new users away. The community is only slowly warming for moving it's Q&A away from mailing-list to the more open SO platform. Some of the fluff was also due to the requirement of using the DigitalMicrograph word in the text.)