# What tag to use for question in a new programming language?

Tags: support, tags

Normally each programming language has its own tag for questions about code in that language. This means questions for a newly released programming language need a new tag. The standard way to add a tag for a new language to Stack Overflow before earning 1,500 reputation is to ask a question without the tag and then [request in a comment to your question that someone else edit it in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134893/229356). But in order to leave the comment, the asker has to ask the question to begin with.

- I've tried posting with no tags at all; I got an error message "Please enter at least one tag; see a list of popular tags."
- I've considered posting with only a meta tag, but [those are considered harmful](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

So how should the asker work around not being able to ask at all because no tag exists for that language? Which of the following is the most acceptable?

- Use a tag for the platform if one exists.
- Ask a question about interoperability with a given other language that already has a tag.
- Wait until someone with 1,500 reputation deems the language "notable" enough to be discussed on Stack Overflow by asking the first question about it. (Suggested by Deduplicator in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268384/a-new-tag-or-a-new-stackexchange-site-advice-requested#comment76233_268384))

Comment: You could always use an inferior tag, and ask in chat as well as a comment so it gets cleaned up quickly. I did something similar on Arqade: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/162895/revisions (asked for the new tag in a deleted comment)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That's what I'm trying to ask: which "inferior tag" to use first.

Comment: Pick one thats remotely related. Perhaps not a language tag, but one related to what you are trying to do.

Comment: A platform tag, one or two problem specific tags, leave space for the language-tag. Then a comment asking for creation of the omitted language-tag, with link to the language-reference if possible. Someone will be happy to oblige any halfway reasonable request.

Comment: If for example your new language is called language and it targets Linux, use the Linux tag. Then mention in the question or in a comment that you'd like the language tag to be created.

Comment: I'd personally try and find someone to create it for you (*I did this yesterday*) then you can go and smarten the tag up with adding a wiki.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a tag that is *remotely* related to what you are talking about, then post your comment. A good choice would be one that describes what you are trying to do.

In case you are using a "niche" tag, you could also ask for someone to add the tag in a chat room so it gets addressed quickly.

Per your suggestions, a "platform" tag could be a reasonable choice. Asking *another* question only works if you actually *have* another question, and the third one is unreliable. Just go for whatever you think fits "well enough" that someone will see it and fix it!

Answer (score 5):

You can post it on Meta here if you have a new tag request. Also when posting the new tag request, you must include your references to the new programming language(Official references.). Any one after reading your question will create a tag.After that you can post your question. I saw a similar tag request in  [Android Ethusiast](http://android.stackexchange.com) SE network. See a [sample question](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1839/can-a-tag-be-created-for-motorola-moto-360) here.

Comment: I thought tags had to be connected to an existing question that has already been asked. (The first question on a site would have no tags, but that would be asked during private beta when tags are 1 rep.) To which question would a tag requested on MSO be added in order to get it created?

Comment: Well you could also include your question and then explain that why would you want to create a tag. Showing some definite example will help the tag created faster.

Comment: @tepples Well, *no*. If we did it that way there wouldn't be any tags on the site! I think the only rule to tag creation for a programming language or framework is that it needs to be used by others and not just yourself (otherwise you could create tags for your *own* programming language).

Comment: @cybermonkey There would still be tags on the site, either those created during private beta or those created later by mods or 1500s. My "notable enough" remark related to your "otherwise you could create tags for your own programming language".

Answer (score -10):

I feel the cleanest way to do this would be a special [new-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-language) (or something like this).

The advantages are apparent:

1. You can tag and hence ask the question.
2. This tag already documents what would have to be posted as a comment otherwise
3. This tag makes it much easier to find questions that need a new language added (there could even be a special review queue?)

The only downside I see (for now), is that it might be misused to post questions without having a "real" tag.

Comment: No. This is a meta-tag and they aren't welcome - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: @ChrisF: I am well aware of that but they aren't there to stay but to get the question out and to indicate that it needs attention/a real tagging.

Comment: The problem is that they *will* stay. Better to post a comment, go to chat or come to meta asking for a user with sufficient rep to create the tag.

Comment: @ChrisF: Hence the review queue idea to get them gone quickly (well, with a tag in place you don't really need the queue as well, you just want to minimize the usage of this tag to zero). And without the tag you first have to search for a replacement before getting the question posted to add the comment. The meta way might be sufficient.